# Assets 2.05 + Wygwam 2.7 - Paths Broken

Tags: wygwam, assets, bug

Relinked a bunch of Assets in Wygwam fields to take of advantage of the dynamic link to the Asset. Moved the Assets from a local file upload source to and S3 source. As a result, assets paths now look like this when rendered in  a Wygwam field on the front-end:

```
<img src="{assets_412:http://s3.amazonaws.com/API/images/about/filename.jpg}" />
```

Looks like a bug? Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've got a bug report posted about this, but I do not have a fix for it at the moment. I've added a note to update you here once the release is in that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks Lisa!

Just an FYI, this is currently working for me:

In Wygwam file `helper.php` I added the following line of code after line `889`:

`preg_match_all("/\\{assets_(\\d*):((.*)(\\}))/uU", $data, $matches);`

On line `889`,  it appears the when replacing the `{assets_xxx}` tags the code assumes there is also a `{filedir_xxx}` tag after the colon. In my experience this isn't always the case, which means those never get parsed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you found out, Synergema!  I'm glad you were able to get it working for your site. :)

Comment: Synergema - I've got a fix locally I can send you if you want to test it out.  Shoot an email to support@pixelandtonic.com if you do.